# the horizontal images was am working on with tailwindcss using flex, now the images is not inline with the text

Tags: html, tailwind-css

[image]

The images are not in line with the text, I use flex for the layout

---

[image]

I that the imaGES TO be horizontal which they are but the images and the text are not in line with each other, some images are even longer than each other